# Given a static time domain signal, why does the magnitude oscillate in the frequency domain after FFT?

Tags: fft, c

I'm trying to:

- Generate a sine wave in the time domain (locally within my program at 500 Hz).
- Analyze it with FFT
- Print the results in the frequency domain.

The expected results are that since the sine wave doesn't change its characteristics (I just keep increasing the `t` variable for each invocation of the function), and stays at 500 Hz, I should get a **constant magnitude** of the signal in the frequency domain.

Actual results, are that the magnitude of the 500 Hz signal in the frequency domain **rather wildly bounces up and down**.

Here I have two screenshots of the plot. Please notice the magnitude of the signal changing between each iteration. It pulsates up and down, almost like the sine wave itself.

[image: Low magnitude of 500 Hz]

[image: High magnitude of 500 Hz]

And just to be sure, I've also plotted the sine wave in the time domain, and checked that it is a nice, continuous function between each invocation (each invocation of the sine generate function generates 512 bytes of data, the plot is for 1000 bytes, to see it is continuous between invocations):

[image]

Why does this happen? I've thought about normalization, but just multiplying or dividing everything by some *constant* wouldn't get rid of this oscillating behavior? Do I need to do something with the imaginary part of the FFT results?

To reproduce, put this in a file live.gnu and plot it with `gnuplot live.gnu`:

```
set xrange[0:22000]
set yrange[0:1.0]
set boxwidth 100.0
set style fill solid plot "outfile.log" with boxes
pause 2
reread
```

I have attached a minimally reproducible example of the code (screenshots are from exactly this code):

Compile with:

> gcc fftw_example4.c -lm -lfftw3 -o fftw_example4

```
/**
 *
 * Minimal reproducible version of oscillating magnitude of signal in the frequency domain.
 *
 * 1: Generate a sine wave, with minor random variations.
 * 2: Do FFT.
 * 3: Write the results to a file (and also print to screen).
 *
 * Notice the 500 Hz signal in the frequency domain, its magnitude changes for each iteration of the while(1) loop.
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE 512
#define RESULT_BUFFER_SIZE (INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE / 2 + 1)
#define SAMPLE_RATE 44100

#define REAL 0
#define IMAG 1

#define FREQ 0
#define MAGN 1

#define OUTFILE "./outfile.log"

int generate_sine(double gain, double frequency, double *input_buffer, int input_buffer_size)
{
    static unsigned int t = 0;

    memset(input_buffer, 0, sizeof(double) * input_buffer_size);

    for(int i = 0; i < input_buffer_size; i++) {
        double sample = gain * sin(((double) t++ * M_PI * 2.0 * frequency) / (double) (SAMPLE_RATE));

        input_buffer[i] = sample;
    }

    return 0;
}

int analyze_init(fftw_plan *plan, double *input_buffer, int input_buffer_size, fftw_complex *result_buffer)
{
    unsigned flags = 0;

    *plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(input_buffer_size, input_buffer, result_buffer, flags);

    return 0;
}

int analyze_frequencies(fftw_plan *plan, double *input_buffer, int input_buffer_size, fftw_complex (*result_buffer)[RESULT_BUFFER_SIZE], int result_buffer_size)
{
    fftw_execute(*plan);

    for(int i = 0; i < result_buffer_size; i++) {
        (*result_buffer)[i][MAGN] = (double) 2.0 / (double) (result_buffer_size) * fabs((*result_buffer)[i][REAL]);
        (*result_buffer)[i][FREQ] = i * (SAMPLE_RATE / (double) input_buffer_size);
    }

    return 0;
}

int print_frequencies(fftw_complex (*result_buffer)[RESULT_BUFFER_SIZE], int result_buffer_size)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(OUTFILE, "w");

    if(!f) {
        perror("fopen");

        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < result_buffer_size - 1; i++) {
        if((*result_buffer)[i][FREQ] >= 300 && (*result_buffer)[i][FREQ] <= 600)
            printf("%f %f\n", (*result_buffer)[i][FREQ], (*result_buffer)[i][MAGN]);

        fprintf(f, "%f %f\n", (*result_buffer)[i][FREQ], (*result_buffer)[i][MAGN]);
    }

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double input_buffer[INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    fftw_plan plan;
    int result_buffer_size = RESULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
    fftw_complex result_buffer[RESULT_BUFFER_SIZE];

    analyze_init(&plan, input_buffer, INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE, result_buffer);

    while(1) {
        generate_sine(1.0, 500, input_buffer, INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE);

        if(analyze_frequencies(&plan, input_buffer, INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE, &result_buffer, RESULT_BUFFER_SIZE) < 0) {
            exit(1);
        }

        print_frequencies(&result_buffer, RESULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    }

    fftw_destroy_plan(plan);

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compute the magnitude of the complex output of the FFT instead of just taking the magnitude of its real part. If $X[k]$ is the (complex-valued) $k^{th}$ frequency bin, its magnitude is

$$\big|X[k]\big|=\sqrt{\left(\textrm{Re}\big\{X[k]\big\}\right)^2+\left(\textrm{Im}\big\{X[k]\big\}\right)^2}$$